# AVFormatContext error: I can't get the AVFormatContext

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I get this error -12 from AVERROR(EONEM) when testing if the AVFormatContext is set up. But I don't understand what It means and what to do. I also get a numeric error (12) when testing the avformat_open_input().
I have used the function av_strerror() in order to get the string error associated to these numeric ones but that function causes errors too. So undefined it.
What should I do to fix the errors? Here is a piece of my code.

```
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"

string myFile="C:/Users/Username/Downloads/Video/QGRAPHICS.mp4";
char *char_array=&myFile[0];

AVFormatContext *avformat_alloc_context();
AVFormatContext *av_format_ctx=NULL; 
/**if av_format_ctx is not null, it means AVFormatContext is allocated**/
if(!av_format_ctx){
    cout<<" Format Context allocated "<<endl;
}


/**I still don't understand why the file can't be opened here**/
if(avformat_open_input(&av_format_ctx, &char_array[0],NULL, NULL)!=0){`cout<<" File not opened"<<endl<<endl;
     cout<<avformat_open_input(&av_format_ctx, &char_array[0],NULL, NULL)<<endl;
     }`
avformat_close_input(&av_format_ctx);
avformat_free_context(av_format_ctx);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont preallocate `av_format_ctx`. Just set it to NULL and let `avformat_open_input` allocate it for you.

```
AVFormatContext *av_format_ctx = NULL;
int err = 0;
 if( err = avformat_open_input(&av_format_ctx, &char_array[0],NULL, NULL)!=0){
     cout<<"File successfully opened"<<endl;
     return false;
   }
     else { cout<< err << endl;}

avformat_close_input(&av_format_ctx);
avformat_free_context(av_format_ctx);
```

Comment: Thank you @szatmary! You helped me resolve the problem with AVFormatContext. But I still get -12 error from avformat_open_input(), which I don't understand.

Comment: Post your complete code. I have no idea what type char_array or how it is set.

Comment: Edit the question, Don't post it in comments.

Comment: Hey szatmary! If you read this don't bother looking at my code again because I have managed to get a string value of this "mysterious" -12 error. It says **cannot allocate memory**. What I have to do is to find out the real problem behind this because I have enough space left on my hard to read a 4mn MP4 video. **Big thanks to you**

Comment: I modified the code. It works fine for the the allocation of the format context but fails to open the files, no matter the OS or the computer i use to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from this line

```
if( avformat_open_input(&av_format_ctx, char_array,NULL, NULL)!=0)
```

you should replace with

```
if( avformat_open_input(&av_format_ctx, char_array,NULL, NULL)==0)
```

because avformat_open_input returns 0 on success

For AVFormatContext preallocation it depends on what type of media do you want to open for file it can be NULL but for custom IO it is preferable to preallocate it

Comment: Hey Olivier Ayache! I really appreciate your efforts. I admit I made a mistake giving instruction to output **File successfully opened** rather than **failed to open the file**. I get the output **File successfully opened** here because avformat_open_input() doesn't return 0. In that case I should have instructed **Failed to open the file**

Comment: Ok so even if it is not necessary I think you should focus on understand why a simple avformat_alloc_context() does not work. What are your FFmmeg version and OS ?

Comment: It does work now! The problem is avformat_open_input(), which returns -12 instead of 0. Unfortunately i don't understand what -12 means as error.